# Cannot install sty file

Tags: texlive

I have spent quite a few hours researching how to do this, but still cannot understand how to add a missing `.sty` file on my linux mint machine.

I have installed texlive by:

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-base
```

I then tried to compile my .tex document:

```
pdflatex filename.tex
```

I got the error message that the endfloat.sty is missing.

So I tried to install it, by first trying to find where my sty files are:

```
whereis texlive
```

which returns `/usr/share/texlive`
, then after a bit of searching I found the other `.sty` files are in their own directories within `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex`.

I tried to make a path then to put my missing `.sty` file in using the sudo command:

```
sudo mkdir endfloat
```

which made the directory

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/endfloat
```

I changed into that directory, and then did

```
sudo wget https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/obsolete/macros/latex209/contrib/misc/endfloat.sty
```

But when I reran:

```
pdflatex filename.tex
```

Still it did not compile because it says the `.sty` file is missing.

Comment: Can't you install it with TeXLive Package Manager (`tlmgr`)?

Comment: Instead of screwing up your system directories, install the [`texlive-latex-extra`](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/texlive-latex-extra) package which contains `endfloat`.

Comment: Also, you haven't installed TeXlive, but merely a tiny part of it (`texlive-latex-base`).  To actually install TeXlive, install the package [`texlive-full`](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/texlive-full).

Comment: Instead of screwing up your system directories, you can also screw up your `$TEXMFHOME` (usually `~/texmf`).

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
$ apt-cache search endfloat
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages
```

Then install `texlive-latex-extra`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Installation should go without any problem. Then verify:

```
kpsewhich endfloat.sty
```

The above should show where the style file has been installed.

And in future occasions, please remember that while manually copying style files may be interesting, this is challenging as well, you should know what you are doing.